# how to show UI objects code in xcode?

Tags: xcode

in one part of my project I need to create some UI objects programmatically, can I just customize my UI Objects like labels,... visually in storyboard then simply copy/paste generated code relevant to that object?
I searched in xcode menu but I couldn't find this but once I saw it in a tutorial in youtube.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can customize the UI Classes or any other class, Like I have customize UILabel Class as UILabelExtended

> UILabelExtended.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

/*  **********************************************************************************************
        This class inherit the class UILabel and extend the features of UILabel. 
    ********************************************************************************************** */
@interface UILabelExtended : UILabel {
   __unsafe_unretained id  customDelegate;
    id  objectInfo;
    SEL selector;
}

@property (nonatomic,assign) SEL selector;;
@property (nonatomic,assign) id  customDelegate;
@property (nonatomic,retain) id  objectInfo;
@end

@interface UILabel(UILabelCategory)
- (void)setHeightOfLabel;
- (void)setWidthOfLabel;
- (void)setHeightOfLabelWithMaxHeight:(float)maxHeight;
- (void)setWidthOfLabelWithMaxWidth:(float)maxWidth ;
@end
```

> UILabelExtended.m

```
#import "UILabelExtended.h"


@implementation UILabelExtended
@synthesize selector,customDelegate, objectInfo;

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if(self.selector)
        if([self.customDelegate respondsToSelector:self.selector]) {
            [self.customDelegate performSelector:self.selector withObject:self];
            return;
        }
}

- (void)dealloc {

    self.customDelegate = nil;
    self.selector = NULL;
    self.objectInfo = nil;
}
@end


@implementation UILabel(UILabelCategory)

- (void)setHeightOfLabel {
    UILabel* label = self;

    //get the height of label content
    CGFloat height = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(label.bounds.size.width, 99999) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping].height;
    //set the frame according to calculated height
    CGRect frame = label.frame;
    if([label.text length] > 0) {

        frame.size.height = height;
    } 
    else {
        frame.size.height = 0;
    }
    label.frame = frame;
}


- (void)setWidthOfLabel {
    UILabel* label = self;

        //get the height of label content
    CGFloat width = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(99999, label.bounds.size.height) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping].width;
        //set the frame according to calculated height
    CGRect frame = label.frame;
    if([label.text length] > 0) {

        frame.size.width = width+5;
    } 
    else {
        frame.size.width = 0;
    }
    label.frame = frame;
}

- (void)setHeightOfLabelWithMaxHeight:(float)maxHeight {
    UILabel* label = self;

    //get the height of label content
    CGFloat height = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(label.bounds.size.width, maxHeight) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping].height;
    //set the frame according to calculated height
    CGRect frame = label.frame;

    if([label.text length] > 0) {
        if (height > maxHeight) {
            frame.size.height = maxHeight;
        }
        else {
            frame.size.height = height;
        }

    } 
    else {
        frame.size.height = 0;
    }
    label.frame = frame;
}

- (void)setWidthOfLabelWithMaxWidth:(float)maxWidth  {
    UILabel* label = self;

    //get the height of label content
    CGFloat width = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(99999, label.bounds.size.height) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping].width;
    //set the frame according to calculated height
    CGRect frame = label.frame;
    if([label.text length] > 0) {

        if (width > maxWidth) {
            frame.size.width = maxWidth;
        }
        else {
            frame.size.width = width;
        }
    } 
    else {
        frame.size.width = 0;
    }
    label.frame = frame;
}
@end
```

Comment: I didn't mean this, let me give you an example:
when I add a label and change its properties how can I see the code which xcode has generated for particularly this label then simply copy it to use it somewhere else

Comment: To Use this code, You have to create UILabelExteneded.h and .m file copy and paste the code from here. And when you have to use this Class import UILabelExtended.h in that class, Take a object of UILabelExtended class, Like: UILabelExtended *lbl = [[UILabelExtended allc]]initWithFrame:yourFrame]; or in IB file take a UILabel and change its class to UILabelExtended. Now you can use the methods have defined in this class like: [lbl setHeightOfLabel]; I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you man, your answer is so close to what I want, I would be thankful if you give me more information as I am beginner.
I am using a SDK which allow me just add one overlay on the screen(which is camera) as I want to show more objects I want to define a UIView and then add what I want to show on this UIView then use this code : reader.cameraOverlayView=subView; which works fine.
my problem is creating and adding these objects to the subView.
I tried this:

Comment: I've added TestViewController.m and TestViewController.h and connected it to a View controller in storybord.
then I added myLabel property in TestViewController.h and customized it as I wanted then I imported TestViewController.h in ViewController.m AND PROBLEM IS HERE when I want to add myLabel from TestViewController to myView in ViewController.m with this code:
`code` [self addSubview:testView.myLabel];

Comment: Than what is the problem. if You want to use myLabel class methods in ViewController.m Import your Extended class in this file also and use your extended method (if you got warning than typecast your nyLabel object)here. Have you got what i mean to say?

Comment: thanks for your answer the idea is correct and simple but I don't know what's wrong:
1.how can I typecast it?
2. while I've imported my TestViewController.h in ViewController.m I've got this error: 'No visible @interface for VieController declares the selector addSubview:'

Comment: I have to mention that I can change myLabel text throw ViewController and it shows that I did it well but I have problem with 'addSubview:' methos when I want to add myLablel.

Comment: you can type cast by [(UILabelExtendedClass*)testView.myLabel yourMethod]; or UILabelExtendedClass* lbl = (UILabelExtendedClass*)testView.myLabel; [lbl yourMethod];

Comment: will you show me what the error is? or will you mail me these two file at prateekprem@gmail.com

Comment: Thank you very much !
I just sent it to you.

Comment: change the code [window addSubview:testView.myLabel]; with [window.view addSubview:testView.myLabel]; error will be fixed.. and one another thing [super viewDidLoad]; should be the first line of that method, right now it is at last.

Comment: Hi
I highly appreciate your thought on my issue, now there is no error but it doesn't show it on the screen.
could you please kindly just take a look at the original project (toughly 12 lines) I sent it to your email and tried to explain everything.
the idea is so simple but stopped me at the beginning of my university project on top of that deadline is close and I am beginner

Comment: I've accepted your answer and tried to vote but voting require 15 reputation.
I am still struggling with issue I sent a new email for you.
where can I define some objects pragmatically which I can access them throw all the methods and classes in the project?